# Background for textfield in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a container for each line of my text field as a background. I obtain the number of lines using `computeLineMetrics` and create a `Container` behind each line using `ListView` as the `Background` of each line. However, my problem is that the number of lines and the number of created backgrounds do not correspond and get mixed up.

[image]

Comment: const Text("asd", style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red)) 
Did you know the TextStyle has an already backgroundColor ?

Comment: This is not a text, this is a textfield.

Comment: Text in TextField already has TextStyle and backgroundColor properties??

Comment: I don't want to use TextStyle because I have a custom style for each line and TextStyle just has a background color.

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` has `decoration` property, which can take `InputDecoration` class,
to have a background,
you can pass for example

```
    TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.red,//The base fill color of the decoration's container color if filled is true,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                ),
              )
```

check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html for more details